# jqgrid custom sort on local data on different column

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, local

I have a jqgrid where dataytype is local. The automatic sort is working fine for each column. I want to know if it's possible to sort a different column based on another column.
To explain this better Lets assume I have three columns `OrderNumber`, `Address`, `Phone`, and a hidden column named `State`. When the `Address` column is clicked I actually want to sort like if the `State` column would have been the one clicked.

I'm trying to do this on the `onSortCol` event, I want something like:

```
onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder) {

     if(index === "Address"){
         //CHANGE SORTED COLUMN TO STATE AND MAKE THE SORT              
     }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

If you work with remote data (`datatype:'json'` or `datatype:'xml'`) you can implement any kind of sorting very easy. So I suppose that you mean jqGrid with local data in your question. In the case I would recommend you to use `sorttype` parameter inside of `colModel` defined as function.

You can define for the `Address` column the `sorttype` property which looks like the following:

```
sorttype: function(cellValue, rowObject) {
    return rowObject.State;
}
```

or like this one:

```
sorttype: function(cellValue, rowObject) {
    return rowObject.State + "_" + cellValue;
}
```

The parameter `cellValue` is the contain of the cell which will be used in compare operation to sort the grid. The `rowObject` is the opject which reprecent the full row having `cellValue`. Returnung another value as `cellValue` from the function `sorttype` will follow that **the returened value** will be used in the compare operations instead of the `cellValue`.

In the first example of `sorttype` implementation (see above) the sorting by `Address` column will be done based on the contain of the column with the name `State`. In the second example, the rows having the same state will be additionaly sorted by address.

You can look on the small demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustumSortChange.htm). If you click on the "Tax" column the grid will be sorted by "id" column where the id values will be interpret as integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing server side sorting you would just do this:

```
if(sord == "Address"){
    sord = "State";
}
```

Have you tried doing the same for your client side sorting:

```
onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder) {    
    if(index === "Address"){
        index = "State";              
    } 
},
```

Comment: Yes I tried to do this, but even if you change the index to "State" the sort keeps sorting by "Address".